# Maxcut problem of spatial embedding graphs

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, max-cut

Given a graph $(V,E)$, I'm interested in embedding it into a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that each vertex $v\in V$ becomes a point $x_v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $d(x_v,x_u) \leq 1$ (Euclidean distance) iff $(v,u) \in E$.

I know that Maxcut isn't NP-hard for planar graphs. But what if I consider graphs that can be embedded as above in $\mathbb{R}^2$, do we know if Maxcut is NP-hard in this case? What about the above embedding in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A graph with $d = 2$ representation is called a [unit disk graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk_graph).

The max-cut problem on unit disk graphs is NP-hard [1], even if the planar representation is given as an input.

- [1] Josep Díaz and Marcin Kamiński. "[MAX-CUT and MAX-BISECTION are NP-hard on unit disk graphs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397507000801)." *Theoretical Computer Science* 377 1–3 (2007).